# using regexp to find space separated numeric and alpha numeric values in tcl

Tags: regex

I have a list of numbers (alpha numeric), and I would like to find any numbers in the list that has 0 next to it separated by space.

I'm looping through a list and using regexp but cant seem to get it to work, but does not seem to work.

example of the list and the regexp code shown below.

Kindly help, thank you.

```
17.8965
25
3.3
40.6
1e10
121.78 0
12.2 0
1e10 0


foreach item $list {
set itemNo [regexp {[^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$]\S+0} $item]
}
```

Comment: print $1 if(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)\s+0$/) on pcre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `\S`, exactly the opposite of what you need (`\s`). The latter matches space characters while the former matches everything else. You also seem to have superfluous braces within your regex.

The working version should be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\s+0$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI7cE2/1)